# how to order my posts by time?

Tags: feature-request

How can I see the list of my posts ordered by time?

---

---------Update1:

Under posts, I did mean all posts including comments and updates (I usyally update/edit my posts multiple times).

---- Related questions:

- [How do I search my comments in SF?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/666/to-search-my-comments-in-sf)
- [what's the point in unformatted comments?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/648/whats-the-point-in-unformatted-comments)

Answer (score 3):

On https://serverfault.com/users/47886 you can sort your Q & A by time.

Comment: Under posts, I did mean all posts - including comments.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are having problem is that you are not using the system as intended.  This is not a **forum**.  This system does not work well when you try to `learn through discussion` as you put it.  This is not a discussion site.

Anyway given your mis-use of the system there is still one place you can look that may give you want you want.  See this page https://serverfault.com/users/47886?tab=activity

Comment: +1 They are not suppose to be posts, they are suppose to be distinct answers and questions for other people to easily get their answers from.