# How do I search my comments in SF?

Tags: feature-request

I am searching (with google) questions with answers in SF in both of which I have commented. There are no results even though I remember some exact keywords and phrases (for example, "keep going", "from developer", etc.). But google gives zero results on searching SF by vgv8 + any keywords from comments:

- [Google search results by vgv8 "keep going" site:serverfault.com](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=vgv8+%22keep+going%22+site%3Aserverfault.com&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=vgv8+%22keep+going%22+site%3Aserverfault.com&gs_rfai=&fp=9cebbf5a0cce78cd)

How can I search through comments in SF?

Can this feature be added?

Another, unrelated question: how do I use the built-in search box which is in the upper right corner of SF webpages, mean?

---

--------- **Update1**

**@Ward,**

I remeber quite well and there are dozens such my comments. Should I give a list of them here?

For ex.,

- [Sharepoint 2010 - "We did not find any results for" keyword](https://serverfault.com/questions/169146/sharepoint-2010-we-did-not-find-any-results-for-keyword)

has in my comment to answer the phrase "Keep going"

Your string does not give any result from comment. It is from answer or question.

There are abcolutely no results from comments. NADA, zero, null. They are not searchable. The comments in SF are a waste for internet community.

**Can you give me a single result from any  comment?**

Answer (score 3):

For questions regarding *how* Stack Exchange features work, please read MSO.  Comment searching has been asked about [multiple times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=search+comments) over there.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you've forgotten the exact phrase you're looking for.  googling

```
vgv8 "Edit3 in original post" site:serverfault.com
```

seems to work fine.

Comment: plz see Update1.

Comment: It works better if you put your comments on an answer right after the answer, not in the question.  The phrase "Edit 3 in original post" is from your comment on the answer given by Testlabs and edited by GregD.

Comment: Yeah, I checked it again, the google search I listed returns a result, and the quoted text is from one of your comments.  As other answers have said, you'd have to look on meta.stackoverflow.com to get more info on what works and doesn't work for searching comments.  Finally (not that I expect you to pay attention), why would you add a comment pointing back changes made to the OP?  Why not make your comments as a comment on the actual answer?